# Split string using special parameters

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, split

I have the following string:

```
1,1,1,0,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,
```

---

```
0-->rupture
2-->continuity
```

---

- When i have 1s between two **0s** it means that i have a **document**
  [0,1,1,1,0] = D
- when i have 1s between a **2** and a **0** it means that i have a **fragment** [2,1,...,1,0] = f and i add all the fragments to a list of fragments **F** and it signifies the end of the sub-fragments
- when i have 1s between a **2** and a **2** it means that i also have a **fragment** [2,1,...,1,2] = f

---

As a solution I must have in the end :

- 3 documents D1,D2,D3 which are located between the indices **[0,3]**,
  **[15,18]**, **[18,21]**
- A Fragment F between **[3,15]** containing 3 sub-fragments , **f1** between [3,6] ,**f2** between [6,11] and **f3** between **[11,15]**.

> Note: We consider that the string starts with a **0** and ends with  a **0**
>   This is why we have a document between **[0,3]** and another document between **[18,21]**

---

I am trying to formulate this problem but i can't come up with a solid idea. Please tell me if it is clear. and what can I use as an algorithm to help solve this problem, can I use a specific data-structure like a tree...

Thank you,
Hani.

Comment: Just design a state machine using pen & paper which is able to process the sequence of numbers according to the three rules you described.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe you can that I can only solve it by a state machine? I can't use another datastructure?

Comment: You can do this by simply traversing the list once and keeping track of the last position of 0 or 2 and its type. When you encounter another 0 or 2, then do whatever and continue.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal what I was thinking si since i have the indices of the 0s and 2s i can use them. But = maybe it's not a good way.

I can start by extracting the incides of the 0s and put them in vector then 2s and put them in a vector the use the indices to traverse the string

Comment: @AbhishekBansal what do u mean by the **last position**

Comment: Be careful, your result seems to imply that we consider the begining of the string to be preceeded by and zero and also the string to have an extra zero. It must be stated in your spec.

Comment: Yes @Jonah i'll add it ok. That's true, it's also a problem that i was thinking about true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your string is:

```
1,1,1,0,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1
```

Initialize `lastPos = 0, lastType = 0 {lastType = 0 for 0 and 2 for 2}`

Traverse the array. You find the next `0` at position `3`. Since `lastType` was equal to `0`, you know that you have found a sequence of `1s` between `2 zeroes`. Do whatever.

```
Make lastType = 0, lastPos = 3.
```

Continue till the end.

```
Order of time complexity: O(n)
Order of space complexity: O(1)
```

Comment: yes @AbhishekBansal I think it's a simplest way to dit. I just add then the **3** conditions that I mentioned above.

Comment: @HaniGoc Yes whenever you encounter a 0 or a 2, just check which combination it gives with lastType and proceed accordingly.